# How to choose different adapter using `netsh wlan set hostednetwork`(Windows 10)

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, usb, netsh

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-turn-your-windows-10-pc-wireless-hotspot) to set up a Wifi hotspot from my Windows 10 PC.

When I run `netsh set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=Your_SSID key=Your_Passphrase`, I think it uses the adapter called `Wi-Fi`. I have a USB Wifi dongle that I want to use for my hotspot, which is listed as `Wi-Fi 2`.

Is there a way I can change the above command to use the USB dongle instead of my laptop's built-in Wifi adapter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key here is to disable the adapters that you don't want the hostednetwork to start on. If you only have one active adapter and run:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=Your_SSID key=Your_Passphrase
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

then it will auto assign itself to that adapter. ( If you do not know the names of your network adapters, you can get a list by entering `netsh wlan show drivers` at the command prompt. Be sure to put the adapter name in quotes in the following commands if there is a space in the names.)

Since you have 2 wireless adapters, wifi1 and wifi2, and you want it to run on wifi2, you can disable wifi1, run script, then enable wifi1 again. This forces hostednetwork on wifi2.

Code:

```
netsh interface set interface name="Wi-Fi1" admin=disabled
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=Your_SSID key=Your_Passphrase
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
netsh interface set interface name="Wi-Fi1" admin=enabled
```

Note: May need to run this batch as administrator.

Comment: But what if you want to have both enabled because you want to create a brdige between them o because you want to use them for different things?

Comment: @skan They are both enabled. You just turn one off for a brief second to apply your hostednetwork to the desired interface. Note that you cannot apply a hostednetwork (virtual AP) to a bridged interface or bridge an adapter using the AP. "bridging is prohibited between the AP adapter and any other adapters in the system" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have two adapters, I want to use one a client to connect my laptop to my wifi and use the other as an AP to repeat the signal.

Comment: what if you want to run the commands on startup?

Comment: @jerinho then save the above as a .bat file, open Task Scheduler and setup as normal with the trigger being set to the "on startup" option.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you trying to find the interface name you can issue the following command and follow the exising answer.

```
netsh wlan show drivers
```